# Rails Linked Models undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, relational-database

I've been following [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-a-second-model), making modifications where necessary.

I have equivalents of `@post` and `@comment`. My comments are 'questions'. I've tried following this procedure again but to the comments (rather than posts). Comments on comments if you like, these are answers/responses to the questions.

I've not been successful in getting this to work.

```
undefined method 'answers' for nil:NilClass`
```

is the error in `answers/_form.html.erb` which is rendered as part of a comment, which is in turn rendered as part of my post equivalent.

`<%= form_for([@question, @question.answers.build]) do |f| %>` is the line that raises the exception. I'm thinking the problem is that `@question` isn't being given a value for some reason?

Either that or my routes file isn't right (would be my guess at least).

```
resources :posts-equivalent do
 ...
 resources :questions
end

resources :questions do
 resources :answers
end
```

This has had me stumped **all day** - any ideas would be appreciated. If you'd like to see any more code drop a comment and I'll update it here.

**Additional Code:**

Error Message:

```
Showing .../app/views/answers/_form.html.erb where line      #1 raised:

undefined method `answers' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for([@question, @question.answers.build]) do |f| %>
```

Answers Controller:

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
 def create
  @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
  @answer = @question.answers.create(params[:answer])
  redirect_to concept_path(@question.concept)
 end
end
```

Comment: under the undefined method error, it should reference a file and a line number. can you post all that? what is `answers` supposed to be called on? likely that hasn't been created yet, so it's trying to call answers on something that doesn't exist.

Comment: @bennett_an Hope that helps, thanks for the fast response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I sorted this in a different manner. Each question was only ever going to have one answer and so I just gave question an answer attribute and assigned that.

On the post page:

```
...
<%= render @questions %>
<%= render "questions/form" %>
...
```

In _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@concept, @concept.question.build]) do |f| %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :contributor_id, :value => session[:contributor_id] %>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.text_field :question, :placeholder => "Follow-up Question" %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

In the _question.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(question) do |f| %>
 <div id="question">
 "<%= question.question %>" asked by <%= question.contributor.email %> | <%= question.created_at %>. 
<div id="answer">
 - Answer: <%= question.answer %>
 <%= f.text_field :answer, :placeholder => "Respond..." %>
 </div>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Add this to the questions controller:

```
def update
 @question = Question.find(params[:id])
 @question.update_attributes(params[:question])

 @concept = Concept.find(@question.concept.id)
 redirect_to concept_path(@concept)
end
```

And that worked for me, I know it's not what I originally asked but that fixed my problem. Thanks to those who did try to help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your AnswersController is not assigning a value to the @question instance variable. It's not clear what action you are running, but I'm assuming it's either new or edit based on the fact that you have a form. You should have something like this in those actions:

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @answer = @question.answers.new
  end

  def edit
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @answer = @question.answers.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Then you can have a single form shared between new and edit:

```
<%= form_for([@question, @answer]) %>
```

Comment: Im on my phone so I can't really try anything out. However I can remember, there is only one action called create. I thought it was odd too but it works for questions with only create.

Comment: I've added the answers controller. True, there is no show/edit method. However the questions controller looks much the same (has only the create method, and works fine). Why should the answer controller need an extra method?

Comment: Is that the exact code? If so, you are missing an @ before the question variable

Comment: Sorry, that must have been a typo when I was adding the code earlier. There is/was an @ before it - I've updated the question.

Comment: Do you think the problem is with me trying to have multiple level nested resources in my routes file?

Comment: That shouldn't matter. What URL are you going to? The create action should only be accessed with a POST request.

Comment: I'm just going to the equivalent of /post/id e.g. post/8. On that page though there i'm rendering a the questions `<%= render @post.questions %>`. And in that partial I've got the line `<%= render "answers/form" %>` to allow people to answer the question. This line is the line that is calling the error.